# Can a web service talk to another web service?

Tags: web-services, soa

I learned about service oriented architecture yesterday, and I have a question about it.

in order to talk to web service provider the initial communication has to be started by a service consumer. Then does it mean that a web service provider cannot talk to another web service directly (because it is not a consumer)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough information to grasp a full scope of what you're getting at exactly. However, I can say that this statement:

> Then does it mean that a web service provider cannot talk to another web service directly (because it is not a consumer)

Isn't really true. A program can (programmatically) access data provided by a web service. The web service has no real awareness as to what a 'consumer' is. It only sees (programmatically) the data provided by the client (typically browser data, cookies, cache, etc..). But that doesn't stop anyone from opening a bash shell and `curl`ing the website.

This will retrieve any data statically provided by the server. Note that the data may obfuscated using JavaScript as to take measures to prevent any programs outside of a browser environment to access their critical data.

**So the answer to that question, is yes *and* no**.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask this question on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ as it is more relevant to questions regarding programming concepts.

Both from technical and architectural points of view service of course can call another one. Simply, it is changing its role to behave as a consumer for the second service. Just be aware that things may become messy if both services are calling each other both ways to finish their task for a single client request. Though there are often valid scenarios for such behaviour, if both services are managed by the same entity, its worth looking if tasks shouldn't be moved or services merged as this may be a sign of a bad design decisions.

Comment: Or create a facade over the two service orchestrating them?

Answer (score -1):

Any piece of software can talk to a web service as long as it can reach it.

Comment: okay so if a client software talks to a web service to get a work done, and if that service can not do it alone, can that service talk to other services and get the work done, and return it to the client?

Comment: Of course it can, but in the context of a service oriented architecture, you have to ask yourself if you SHOULD do this